# The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I have this code that creates a foreign key to the table P that has to reference to table Ss. At the moment the column that I want to be a fk is bigint, not null and its default is to 0. Is this the impediment?  And the StoredFile column id is not null and is filled with bigint data.

```
alter table P add constraint fk_fileId_p foreign key (fileID)
    references Ss(id)
```

Comment: the column that you want to make a foreign key has a default value ? Sounds like a flaw in your table design because now you have to create a dummy record in the reference table with that default value just to get your foreign key working. Also every new record you insert in this table will be linked to this dummy record. Is that really what you want ?

Comment: Yes. If the Parent table gets updated I want to be able to update the child table as well.

Comment: Jokes1994 I do not understand what you mean with that. A foreign key does not updates the child table in any way. What are you trying to accomplish here ?

Comment: What I want is to have the values from c1.tbl1  to c2.tbl2.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand any of this you have to tell more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add the FK, you have to make sure that storefileID 0 is present in the table StoredFile (e.g. by adding a dummy record) - otherwise the FK validation fails and the constraint can not be created.

Comment: If I don't have the default value, the alter table that creates the column gives me an error that it has to have a default value

Comment: This is why you should add the dummy record with ID 0... lateron you can filter it / change the way it is displayed etc., but for the time being the dummy record is required in order to use the FK.